# How to create video form the still image with music and Text on the images

Tags: image, image-processing, movie

I am looking for the open source or paid tools which help me to create a movie from the still image and music. I also want to put some text on the images.

My main concern is the video quality. I need a high quality video as output.

Can anyone please give me some suggestion.

I also want to know that, can we achieve this with the help of ffmpeg?

I am not interested for GUI tools, I am mainly looking for some API or service which takes input as images,texts,audio and gives output as a video.

OS does not matters. I can go with any os windows or linux.

The quality of the video should High.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't tell us which OS you're using you make it difficult. This is possible with ffmpeg, the output quality depends on your input quality and the output format/codec you choose. Google has lots of ffmpeg tutorials.

[Openshot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) is a great GUI based video editor for Linux and also available for Windows and Mac. Your task would be trivial to achieve using Openshot.